# Transparent UIView on google maps - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview

I'm trying to put a UIView on google maps and make this UIView transparent to be able to see the background map. As in the following image:

[image]

My code is:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapViewContainer: UIView!
    var resultsArray = [String]()
    var googleMapsView : GMSMapView!
    var estacionamientoSelecccionado = Estacionamiento()
    @IBOutlet weak var viewTitutlo: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (estacionamientoSelecccionado?.latitude)!,
                                          longitude: (estacionamientoSelecccionado?.longitude)!, zoom: 15)
    self.googleMapsView =  GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mapViewContainer.frame, camera: camera)
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (estacionamientoSelecccionado?.latitude)!, longitude: (estacionamientoSelecccionado?.longitude)!)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "marker_2")!
    marker.map = self.googleMapsView
    self.viewTitutlo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.viewTitutlo.isOpaque = false
```

And the result I get putting the uiview as UIColor.clear is:
[image]

My interface:
[image]

Comment: my guess is your `UIView` is under `GMSMapView`, try to set `UIViewController's view.backgroundColor = .green` or something and check if I am right.

Comment: If I set self.view.backgroundColor = .green self.viewTitutlo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear self.viewTitutlo.isOpaque = false, The background of my self.viewTitutlo is green but if i set self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear, the background is black.

Comment: well, then your problem is that your layout is wrong, you have `GMSMapView` bottom to `UIView` top, something like this.

Comment: How could I fix this?, should i change the way the map is loaded into the view. Now I charge it like this: self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView)

Comment: why do not you add it using storyboard? just add `UIView` (or `UIImageView` I am not sure) and change its class to be `GMSMapView`

Comment: I added the map as you say and this worked. I used storyboard and i set the class to GMSMapView. I deleted this code: self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapsView) and it is working. thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You should select view on storyboard and change color property with opacity

or

```
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Comment: I get the same result as using self.viewTitutlo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear. I think the problem is how to load the map into the view.